# I'm thankful (to/of) him for caring for my mother when I wasn't at home

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

> I'm thankful (to/of) him for caring for my mother when I wasn't at home.

Which is the proper preposition to write there?

I already know that 'to' must be in the blank. But I think 'of' is fine as well, in that 'of' means 'relate' between 'thankful' and 'him'.

That is to say, it would mean that I am feeling thankful to him is related to him directly.

Why is 'of' not correct semantically?

Comment: I think you need a better explanation why you think "of" can be used here. Or actual examples where it is used that way. Or a dictionary definition that explains it.

Comment: In my opinion:

"I'm thankful to him for X."

'To' is used because gratitude is shown or given to another person. The 'movement' of the action, from the speaker to the receiver, therefore makes 'to' the proper preposition to be used. 

'Of' doesn't seem to fit as it doesn't show 'direction'/'movement' for the action, RE: 'showing gratitude/being thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I think "I'm **grateful to** him" would be more idiomatically usual English.  "Thankful" isn't usually expected to point to a particular object, and using it that way would sound awkward to a native speaker.

If you were going to use "thankful", it should probably be "I'm thankful **that he cared for my mother**".

As for the difference between "of" and "to", "I'm grateful to him" sounds as if your thanks are addressed definitely *to him*.  "I'm grateful of him" sounds almost as if you're thanking someone else for giving you him.